# Bulk opening of several node edit screens

Tags: 7

is there a way to open up several nodes to edit at once? At `/admin/content` I can mark all of the nodes that I want to edit, but I still have to click each edit link individually.

Is this something that I could do by adding an action to the "Update Options" dropdown?

**Edit**
The reason for the mass editing is that I have added a new field to a content type. I would like to add unique values to that field for preexisting nodes.

Comment: What would you like to edit? From a UI point of view, it makes a huge difference if you want to edit all body texts or if you just want to change the author on all selected nodes. The update options are especially useful if you want to apply the same value (eg. published = true) to all nodes.

Comment: @marcvangend I have added a new field to the content type. I would like to add unique values to that field for preexisting nodes.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I am aware, no module will do this out of the box. However in saying that there is a potential solution in:

1. [Installing Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) (VBO)
2. Writing a custom action that happens on each selected node

From the VBO page:

**How can I write an action that performs a function on all selected nodes AT ONCE?**

You need to write a node operation instead of an action. Whereas actions get called *once for every selected node*, node operations are called once only, and they are passed an array of selected nodes. Check out sirkitree's article for the same concept applied to user operations.
Note: If you use Batch API to execute your actions, VBO will revert to calling the action once per node instead. This is because it doesn't make sense to batch one single action.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have been meaning to study up on VBO for some time now.

Answer (score 1):

[Edit view](http://drupal.org/project/editview) used to allow you to do this, although it hasn't officially been ported to D7 yet, although I believe work has started on that.

Essentially it allows you to build a view which exposed fields of your choice which you can edit all at once.